# How to delete s3 object using s3 image url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I want to delete image from s3 bucket by finding the below url.

> ```
> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3dev-bucket/perspectives/images/3547/original/1.jpg?1471239691
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
Aws.config.update(
credentials: Aws::Credentials.new("access_key_id", "secret_access_key"),
region: "region"
)

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket("bucket")
obj = s3.object('perspectives/images/3547/original/1.jpg')
obj.delete
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`#delete_object()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#delete_object-instance_method):

```
resp = client.delete_object({
  bucket: "s3dev-bucket", 
  key: "perspectives/images/3547/original/1.jpg", 
})
```